# vbs cannot insert dummy data to CSV file with null value

Tags: vbscript

when the script run to a line with null value, the script will stop and quit.  how to fix?

```
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Open
objStream.Type = 2
objStream.Charset = "utf-8"
objStream.LoadFromFile Wscript.Arguments.Item(0)
objStream.LineSeparator = 10
```

Comment: [ADODB.Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/readtext-method) will exit when it encounters the first null. Stream will not be a good way to process text file which contains text and binary data. How about using FileSystemObject and read the text. You can then do null replacement or just ignore it.

Comment: A binary type stream should not exit on null characters.

Comment: He is using a text stream `type=2`.

Comment: Does it work with UTF-8 characters?